# Does the Misc Item drop rate conflict with the Hat drop rate?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I read the wiki, and it stated that for premium players, the drop rate for hats is between 1-6 months, and after a certain period of time, it resets.

Then I read another article for Misc. item drops, and was wondering the drop rate for Misc items were, and whether or not it conflicted with Hat drops (ie, you receive a hat for 1-6 month period, can you get a misc drop? or is it classified as a "hat")

Does the Misc Item's drop time conflict with the Hat's drop time?

Comment: Links to the articles?

Comment: Right now the Official TF2 wiki is down (idk why).  I'll post 'em up when they're okay.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware there is a certain chance you will get a drop at any given time and then a percentage chance what that drop will be, so every time you get a drop there would be say a 0.5% chance it would be a hat (for example not actual figures). I'm pretty sure thats how it used to work but things could have changed since the free update.

So as far as I'm aware when you get a drop its either a hat or an item so as such they do technically conflict